# Setting div height like the rest of browser height

Tags: html, css

The Objective is to set the second div inside the table called (**divRestOfHeight**) taking the rest height of the screen 
I was trying to do it with "height:100%; position absolute" but it sets that div with all height of the screen and not just rest...

I have seen examples with javascript but I would like to know if there's a way to doit with only css.

View:

```
<div id="divMain">
    <div>
        <table id="tTable">
                <tr>
                    <td>                            
                        <div id="divFixedHeight" style="height:200px;background-color: red;width: 100%;position: absolute;">

                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>            
                <tr>
                    <td>                        
                        <div id="divRestOfHeight" style="background-color:pink">                    

                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: table is not a good idea for maintainability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set a block element to 100% height of the screen, you must also set the height of all of it's parent's to 100% height.

For example, let's say you have the following:

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child">
       some content
   </div>
</div>
```

To make `.child` have 100% height, `.parent` must ALSO be set to 100% height.  Like so:

```
html,
body,
.parent,
.child { height: 100%; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you want it to spill outside of the divMain to the bottom of the browser window or you want it to fill the remaining space within the divMain?

As far as I know it will not fill the rest of the browser whilst imbedded in div tags if they dont fill the page.

Try increasing the height of the divMain or making the bottom margin as 0px as to stretch it.

Comment: I want to spill outside of the divMain to the bottom of the browser window ! :) I'll try your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

This code does what you're after

```
<body style="padding: 0; margin: 0;">
  <div id="divMain" style="height: 100%;">                          
    <div id="divFixedHeight" style="height:200px;background-color: red;width: 100%;position: absolute;"></div>                      
    <div id="divRestOfHeight" style="background-color:green; height: 100%;"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Or do you really need those table thingys? It sure look like ugly HTML :/

Comment: Hi Magnus ty for your response! With your post and a link that i have found I will solve my conflict :)  interesting link > http://webdesign.about.com/od/csstutorials/f/set-css-height-100-percent.htm